# Date matching and interpolation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, optimization, interpolation

**Prelude:** I have a large dataset with several hundred thousand records stored in a MySQL database. Greatly simplified, each row has a datetime field to store the date and time at which a telephone call was made and an integer field to store the length of the call.

**Scenario:** I'm busy writing an interpolation function in PHP which generates a range of dates separated by a pre-calculated interval. Each generated date is stored in an associative array with the date used as the key, and each value initialized to 0. The script then queries the database for a list of records and attempts to match the datetime record to the closest date in the pre-generated associative array. When the closest match is found, it simply adds the call duration to the existing value of the array at that index.

**Example of the generated associative array:**

```
$array    =   array(  "2011-01-01 09:00:00" => 0,
                      "2011-01-01 09:30:00" => 0,
                      "2011-01-01 10:00:00" => 0,
                      "2011-01-01 10:30:00" => 0,
                      "2011-01-01 11:00:00" => 0,
                      "2011-01-01 11:30:00" => 0,
                      "2011-01-01 12:00:00" => 0
                   )
```

In the above example, a range of dates is generated using an interval of 30 minutes.

**Example of records from the MySQL database:**

```
+---------------------+----------+
| datetime            | duration |
+---------------------+----------+
| 2011-01-01 09:02:26 |        1 |
| 2011-01-01 09:14:51 |        1 |
| 2011-01-01 10:40:33 |      549 |
| 2011-01-01 11:10:27 |       38 |
| 2011-01-01 11:31:50 |       82 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

Each of these records now needs to be matched to the closest datetime key from the pre-generated array given above and the `duration` value added to the existing value of the match.

**The Problem:**
It's easy enough constructing two nested `for` loops to interate through the records from the database and then linearly run through the associative array to find a match, but this is hugely inefficient, and becomes problematic for large datasets (think bubblesort, that's what this would be roughly equivalent to). A slightly better approach is to linearly loop over the records from the database, and then iterate over the array as a binary tree, which is certainly a lot more efficient, and is possible since both arrays are sorted chronologically.

**The Question:**
Is there a more efficient way of handling this date matching than how I've described in the above problem?

Comment: If both lists are sorted by date/time, you can use merging. Like in mergesort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about dividing the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` of the date by 30 * 60 seconds (30 minutes) and using `ROUND()` for the integer. Then, use `GROUP BY` to group them, and finally, `SUM()` to sum the durations.

```
SELECT SUM(duration), ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) / (30 * 60)) FROM table GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) / (30 * 60))
```

Comment: Although I didn't end up doing it like this, I'm accepting your answer anyway since it gave me a base to work on. My implementation is in PHP and performs a similar calculation to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your current algorithm (if I understand you correctly) looks like this:

1. Get all records
2. Compare the datetime of each record to an array key
3. Incremement the sum of the appropriate array value based on the record

A more efficient method may be:

1. Query the sum of the durations for all records that match the given subset of time
2. Insert the sum into the array with the appropriate key

This allows MySQL to provide optimized math logic and reduces the number of array iterations required by your script. You will increase the number of database queries, but benchmarking will tell you if the tradeoff is worthwhile.